# ADF Self hosted Integration Runtime concurrency limit not editable

Tags: azure-data-factory

In my project I couldn't modify the concurrency limit of SHIR. Somehow Admin is unable to recall where this option was disabled. Can someone please tell me how to make this editable?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you without permission?

Comment: Have specified access to the subscription. Keen to know where to change to make it available for users to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the Integrated runtime is shared. You need to edit the settings in the origin ADF ressource

Answer (score 0):

I think we can create a new Self hosted Integration Runtime for test to see if you have the permission edit the amount of the concurrent jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `concurrentJobsLimit` for an Integration Runtime of subtype Linked is not supported.

Actually, if you try to do it through the corresponding [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/integration-runtime-nodes/update), it will fail like this:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnsupportedIntegrationRuntimeOperation",
    "message": "The operation PatchIntegrationRuntimeNode on integration runtime type Linked is not supported.",
    "target": null,
    "details": null
  }
}
```

The UI is noticing your SHIR is one linked and that's the reason why it is disabling the pencil icon.